# Peste ! comme expression

Tags: expressions

Dans *Manon des Sources*, j'ai rencontré cette exclamation :

[image: citation du livre]

> Peste ! s'écria M. Belloiseau. Et d'où sort-elle ?

J'ai trouvé cette expression dans un dictionnaire qui la décrit comme « vieillie ». Mais je voudrais avoir un peu plus de détail. Où pourrais-je entendre cette expression? Si je l'utilisais, quelle serait votre réaction ?

Comment: le genre d'expression qu'on pourrait entendre dans un film en costume (moyen âge ou grand siècle), en particulier sous le forme "peste soit de..."

Comment: "La peste soit de l'avarice et des avaricieux" (Molière, "L'Avare", 1668)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le verbe ***pester*** est encore utilisé de nos jours mais l'interjection ***Peste !*** ne fait plus partie du lexique courant en France.

Tes interlocuteurs seraient surpris si tu l'employais, un peu comme si tu disais ***Sapristi !*** ou ***Flûte !***

Comment: J'aime bien Tudieu ! aussi ;-)